# Postfix blocking mail

Tags: postfix-mta

I have a weird problem with Postfix blocking some e-mails due to a smtpd_helo_restrictions rule. That looks like this:

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname

The error is that HSI-BW-078-042-xxx-xxx.hsi3.kabel-badenwuerttemberg.de (the last two octets are actually not xxx) apparently is not a FQDN although it looks like one for me. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, my bad. I looked in the wrong spot. The HELO command didn't include the FQDN, but "JohnsPC". Great job, Outlook!